# AdMob Mediation: No fill for ad request

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, ads

I'm currently using AdMob and Swift 5 to integrate ads into my app. The actual ad units in my app are configured with AdMob, but AdMob uses mediation to get ads from AdColony and AppLovin. Test ads show correctly on simulators and physical devices. Live ads only show in simulators.

In the simulator (iOS 13.5):

- When "Limit ad tracking" is turned on or off in Settings, ads show either way.

In the simulator (iOS 14.2):

- When "Allow apps to request to track" is turned on or off, my app attempts to request to track, but will still show ads even if it cannot track.

On an iPhone (iOS 13.5):

- "Limit ad tracking" can be on or off and live ads will not show either way.

On an iPhone (iOS 14.2):

- "Allow apps to request to track" can be on or off, my app attempts to make a request to track, and will not show ads whether accepted or denied.

`Physical iPhone console log:`

```
AdColony [Info] -[ADCNetwork setHost:] Line 42 : Valid reachability object created with host: www.adtilt.com

AppLovinAdapter: Found 1 SDK keys. Please remove any SDK keys you are not using from the AdMob UI.

AdColonyAdapter: Zones that are being configured: (
    vzfbcebdd3803aXXXXXX,
    vza3675f575dbfXXXXXX,
    vzfac9153e28c6XXXXXX,
    vz43bcba3540b3XXXXXX,
    vzcfb95851b9abXXXXXX,
    vz3785ee97e8ffXXXXXX
)

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [ALSdk] Setting plugin version: 6.14.9.0

AdColony [Info] -[ADCDevice init]_block_invoke Line 250 : ADCNetwork status change: 1
AdColony [Info] : AdColony library version: 4.4.1.0 64-bit production
AdColony [Info] : AdColony controller version: 2.7.3

IDFA: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 // This is actually how it appears in the console

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [AppLovinSdk] 
========================================
AppLovin SDK
Version: 6.14.9
Plugin Version: 6.14.9.0
Ad Review Version: 
OS: iOS 13.5
IDFA: <Enable verbose logging to see the IDFA to use for test devices - https://monetization-support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/236114328-How-can-I-expose-verbose-logging-for-the-SDK>
SDK Key: MySDKkeyHere
Model: iPhone12,1
Locale: en_CA
Simulator: 0
Bundle ID: MyBundleIDhere
Has AppLovinSDKResources: true
Test Mode On: false
Verbose Logging On: false
Mediation Provider: admob
TG: 29
===Privacy States===
Please review AppLovin MAX documentation to be compliant with regional privacy policies.

Age Restricted User - false
Has User Consent - true
"Do Not Sell" - false
===App Tracking Transparency===
Authorization Status: Unavailable (-1)
NSUserTrackingUsageDescription Exists: true

========================================

[AppLovinSdk] ERROR [ALSdk] Auto-initing adapters for non-MAX mediation provider: admob
AppLovinAdapter: AppLovin adapter version: 6.14.9.0
AppLovinAdapter: AppLovin SDK version: 6.14.9
AppLovinAdapter: All SDKs completed initialization.

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [ALSdk] Setting plugin version: 6.14.9.0
AppLovinAdapter: Requesting banner of size kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait for zone: e7c60ca56eXXXXXX.
AdColonyAdapter: Requesting banner for zone: vzcfb95851b9abXXXXXX
AdColonyAdapter: Failed to load banner ad: No fill for ad request
AdColony [Info] : Banner ad request failed in zone: vzcfb95851b9abXXXXXX
AdColonyAdapter: Requesting interstitial ad for zone: vz3785ee97e8ffXXXXXX
AdColony [Info] : Interstitial ad request failed in zone: vz3785ee97e8ffXXXXXX
AdColonyAdapter: Failed to load interstitial ad with error: No fill for ad request
[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [ALSdk] Setting plugin version: 6.14.9.0
AppLovinAdapter: Requesting interstitial for zone: 9b7b4f5f9eXXXXXX
```

`Simulator console log:`

```
AdColony [Info] -[ADCNetwork setHost:] Line 42 : Valid reachability object created with host: www.adtilt.com

AppLovinAdapter: Found 1 SDK keys. Please remove any SDK keys you are not using from the AdMob UI.

AdColonyAdapter: Zones that are being configured: (
    vzfbcebdd3803aXXXXXX,
    vza3675f575dbfXXXXXX,
    vzfac9153e28c6XXXXXX,
    vz43bcba3540b3XXXXXX,
    vzcfb95851b9abXXXXXX,
    vz3785ee97e8ffXXXXXX
)

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [ALSdk] Setting plugin version: 6.14.9.0

AdColony [Info] -[ADCDevice init]_block_invoke Line 250 : ADCNetwork status change: 1
[plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000c9e3e0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-000393XXXXXX
AdColony [Info] : AdColony library version: 4.4.1.0 64-bit production
AdColony [Info] : AdColony controller version: 2.7.3

IDFA: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 // This is actually how it appears in the console

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [AppLovinSdk] 
========================================
AppLovin SDK
Version: 6.14.9
Plugin Version: 6.14.9.0
Ad Review Version: 
OS: iOS 13.5
IDFA: <Enable verbose logging to see the IDFA to use for test devices - https://monetization-support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/236114328-How-can-I-expose-verbose-logging-for-the-SDK>
SDK Key: MySDKkeyHere
Model: iPhone12,1
Locale: en_CA
Simulator: 0
Bundle ID: MyBundleIDhere
Has AppLovinSDKResources: true
Test Mode On: false
Verbose Logging On: false
Mediation Provider: admob
TG: 29
===Privacy States===
Please review AppLovin MAX documentation to be compliant with regional privacy policies.

Age Restricted User - false
Has User Consent - true
"Do Not Sell" - false
===App Tracking Transparency===
Authorization Status: Unavailable (-1)
NSUserTrackingUsageDescription Exists: true

========================================

[AppLovinSdk] ERROR [ALSdk] Auto-initing adapters for non-MAX mediation provider: admob
AppLovinAdapter: AppLovin adapter version: 6.14.9.0
AppLovinAdapter: AppLovin SDK version: 6.14.9
AppLovinAdapter: All SDKs completed initialization.

[AppLovinSdk] DEBUG [ALSdk] Setting plugin version: 6.14.9.0
```

I've looked around on many different forums etc and I can't find a solution to this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, as long as test ads show find - your integration should be good. However, I noticed that your AppLovin SDK key is incorrect due to the following logs:

```
SDK Key: MySDKkeyHere
```

I would remedy that issue first, and continue triage if live ads still do not show thereafter.